# RewriteCondition dot all

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to mod_rewrite and have almost gotten something working the way I'd like, but I'm having trouble finding my error.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=product/product&path=123&product_id=56.*$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.gardentowerproject.com/shop/product/garden-tower-2 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

This URL redirects properly: `http://gardentowerproject.com/store/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=56`

This one doesn't: `http://gardentowerproject.com/store/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=56foo`

I'd like to be able to catch URLs with anything after character "6", and I thought .* would do that. Please advise, and thank you.

Comment: how can it match with `..&path=123...` ?

Comment: `I'd like to be able to catch URLs with anything after character "6", and I thought .*` - Can you clarify this with an example?